# Can not get req.params in my sql query

Tags: node.js

I try to select content from database according url.

My code :

controllers :

```
module.exports = function(express){

    var router=express.Router();
    var modele_content=require("../model/content_model");


    router.get('/',function(req,res){
        //res.locals.variable='variable';
        res.render('home/home.html');
    });

    router.get('/:url',function(req,res){
        var param=[req.params.url];
        modele_content.selectRow(param,function(err,data){
            if(err) {
               res.end(err.errno+":"+err.code);
           }
           var data = JSON.parse(data);
           res.render('home/home.html', {content: data[0]});

        });

    });

    return router;
}
```

Model :

```
function selectRow(param,fn){
        pool.getConnection(function(error, connection) {
            var chsql = " SELECT * ";
            chsql += " FROM content ";
            chsql += " WHERE url= ?;"; 
            var query=connection.query(chsql,param, function (error, results, fields) {
                console.log(query.sql);
                connection.release();
                if (error) return fn(error,null);
                return fn(null,results);
            });
        });
    }
    exports.selectRow=selectRow;
```

The result : `1064:ER_PARSE_ERROR`

In model, if I change "?" with an url in my database column, it works. Even in my "`console.log(query.sql)`" I can see the correct query but still have an error...

Can you help ?

Thanks very much !

Comment: Passing URL as a route param can be messy, you may have issues with slashes ;) However could you provide actual output of your `console.log()` when you visit `/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com` or just `/hello-world`?

Comment: The output is "SELECT * FROM content WHERE url='/hello-world' ". In controller when I change "var param=[req.params.url];" with "var param=[req.urll];" it seems to work. I just look for a way to load data from my database according url. I just discover nodeJs ;)

Comment: And with req.params.url what do you get? Req.url is the actual full URL so it's normal ^^ however I say "/..." But it depends on what root you mounted your router